# checking condition for activity

Tags: android, button, android-intent

I have a layout with 3 buttons Create, Show and Setting.
on clicking create and show button they are working fine and getting transferred to next activity whatever it is.
but i need to check for setting button. that is- if password table exists then it should go to password.class and if doesnt exists then to Setting.class.

on trying this code the else statement is showing dead code and not responding.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button create, show, setting;
String pass1,pass2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    create = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Create.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
        }

    });


    show = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Password.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
        }

    }); 


     SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("passmanage", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from password", null);
     c.moveToFirst();
     if(c!=null)
     {
         setting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
         setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Password.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent3, 0);
            }

         }); 
     }   

     else
     {
         setting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
         setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Setting.class);
                 startActivityForResult(myIntent3, 0);
             }

         }); 
     }   


}
```

}

i tried in this way too-

```
setting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("passmanage", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from password", null);
     c.moveToFirst();
     if(c!=null)
     {
         Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Password.class);
         startActivityForResult(myIntent3, 0);
     }   

     else
     {
         Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Setting.class);
         startActivityForResult(myIntent3, 0);
     }

        }});
```

but here also i am getting the error as dead code of else condition.

i tried in this way also

```
 setting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("passmanage", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from password", null);
     c.moveToFirst();
     if(c!=null)
     {
         do
        {
            pass1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("pass"));
            pass2 = c.getString(1);

        } while(c.moveToNext());

         if(pass1.compareTo("")==0 && pass2.compareTo("")==0)
         {
             Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Password.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntent3, 0);
         }
         else
         {
             Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Setting.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntent3, 0);
         }

     }

        }});
```

but it getting closed unexpectedly!

i have one more small doubt. do i need to create intent with different name for different buttons in the same activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your curser c will not be null. If it was you would get a nullpointerexception on c.moveToFirst(). You need to check if it has data.

Comment: you mean to say that i should check that the table has data?

Comment: hey bro i tried in this way also. it getting closed unexpectedly.